# Recreate an RPM from an installed RPM on linux

Tags: linux, rpmbuild

How do I recreate an rpm which is already installed on a system on linux?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191076/how-to-extract-rpm-from-rpm-database-in-redhat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of RPM are you using? If you're using a newer one, I have a trick that might work for you.

Newer versions of RPM have a [transaction safe rollback option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7034); simply use the --repackage command, and it'll generate a package that includes all the idiosyncratic crap of the original install. Mind you, you'll have to actually DO something (e.g rpm -e --repackage rpm_goes_here  which will ERASE the original, while making a package which you SHOULD be able to restore (after you've made a copy), but if you expect this to work perfectly, I have a BRIDGE you might want to buy), so it's a bit of a leap of faith if you don't have a full backup.

There is some configuration involved, and you need to test test test before you try this on something critical, but this may work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will have to do the following:

1] Create a .spec file with all the headers [ http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html ]

You will have to use the rpm -q --queryformat "" to get the header from the already installed rpm. 
Eg. `rpm -q --queryformat "Release: %{RELEASE}\n" installed_rpm`

For getting the files to fill the `%files` Section use the `rpm -ql`  command.

2] run  `rpmbuild -bb specfile`  to generate the rpm file.

Comment: There is a option of recreating it.I was thinking something like that

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option. But if you find one please let me know also.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to recreate an RPM, is to do it from the source RPM. Great tutorial [here](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/patching_rpms.php).

Answer (score 0):

The [deltarpm](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=deltarpm) package can do that:

> A deltarpm contains the difference between an old and a new version of
>   a rpm, which makes it possible to recreate the new rpm from the
>   deltarpm and the old one. You don't have to have a copy of the old
>   rpm, deltarpms can also work with installed rpms.

Comment: It's not feedback either. It would be best omitted entirely.

Comment: Rephrased as an answer.